# Issue while using Camera intent in One plus 6 and Samsung M20

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

I am facing one issue while using Camera intent, In OnActivityResult I am getting `currentPhotoPath`  as null. Tried in Samsung M20(version 10) and One plus (version 10) Implemented the code form Google doc. The same code is working perfectly in Google pixel3(version 11), Redmi note 7s(version 9), Vivo.(version 8.1).

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Adding code also:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    String currentPhotoPath;
    TextView textView;
    File photoFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath onStart  " + currentPhotoPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath onResume  " + currentPhotoPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath onRestart  " + currentPhotoPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath onPause  " + currentPhotoPath);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.camera.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath file photoFile  " + photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 2) {
                Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath onActivityResult  " + currentPhotoPath);
                if (currentPhotoPath != null) {
                    textView.setText(currentPhotoPath);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong, Unable to pick PDF file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath file path  " + image.getAbsolutePath());
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.v("currentPhotoPath", "currentPhotoPath file  " + currentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Lesson one: Android OS can kill your activity at any moment when your activity is not the top one.

When the camera app becomes the top one your activity is killed apparently.

Save your variable in onSaveInstanceState() and load it back in onCreate() when its parameter is not null.